# Session Filter redirect trouble

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

I have problems with AccessFilter in java web. When I am calling /main.jspx it redirect to the login.jsp. But when I am trying to log-in some error appeared

```
public class AccessFilter implements Filter {

    private FilterConfig filterConfig;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        Client client = (Client) session.getAttribute("client");        
        if (client != null) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(
                    ConfigurationManager.getInstance().getProperty(ConfigurationManager.LOGIN_PAGE_PATH));
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        this.filterConfig = null;
    }

}
```

web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>AccessFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>ua.kpi.shop.filter.AccessFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AccessFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/jsp/main.jspx</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/jsp/pokemons.jspx</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Error:
HTTP Status 404 - /PokemonsShop/login.jspx

type Status report

message /PokemonsShop/login.jspx

description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: Normally in your server output you will have the full local path to the file not found, you will be able to find what is the problem with that I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

`filterConfig.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher` takes the absolute path as opposed to `request-getRequestDispatcher`. Though whether that is the solution I cannot say.

Answer (score 0):

Two things came into my head when seeing your message:
1) Did you check whether the client object is null or not ? May be when executing the login action (method) you are not setting correctly the client into session ?
2) In the server error, it says "not found /PokemonsShop/login.jspx" but in your filter mapping you are mentioning /jsp/xxx. Would it be because your login page is under the folder jsp and you are redirecting (in the filter) to /PokemonsShop/login.jspx, which should be under webapp root folder to be accessible.
Hope one of them be of help